# How do I line the SELECT LIST with the rules of of VIEW creation in this query?

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to understand exactly where I went wrong in this query

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the 2nd column does not have a name. Thus breaking the rules of view creation.